# What can cause a paged pool increasing?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management

i'm having problems with paged pool resource on windows.

I'm writing a dll with c++ and, when i execute it, in "task manager" i can see the paged pool value increase.

What can cause a growth of this value? allocating mem (with malloc, calloc, etc..)? something else?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [what can be the reason of a paged pool leak?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637398/what-can-be-the-reason-of-a-paged-pool-leak)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you're indirectly causing something in kernel mode (i.e. ntoskrnl or drivers) to allocate memory. Paged pool is the rough equivalent of heap memory for kernel mode. If this isn't actually causing an issue for you, it's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Unless you're creating thousands of threads, probably not. Hans's reply in another thread is a good one, check for handle leaks. AppVerifier can help you with this.

Comment: Well, i'm actually creating thousands of threads :)
That was the point, it seems that i have also to explicity deallocate the space memory of the parameters passed to the thread function...

Comment: "it seems that i have also to explicity deallocate the space memory of the parameters passed to the thread function" - hwhat?

Comment: sorry for my english, i mean you have to call the HeapFree function on the thread function argument.  [link] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516(v=vs.85).aspx)